# Inject 2FA into Laravel Authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, two-factor-authentication

I'm working on adding Google 2FA to my Laravel 5.5 app that is using the Laravel generated authentication methods.

I have the 2FA portions figured out, but I cannot for the life of me find where to inject the code to add the 2FA check to the login process.

I have already modified the form to show the 2FA field on the login form, but where do I put that check? I see the options to add it as middleware and apply that to certain pages, but I don't want to require 2FA on multiple pages, just on login.

I did finally find the controller file that handles authentication (vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php), but I don't see anywhere in there that I could add the 2FA check (obviously I would overwrite the method in my own file, not modify the vendor file).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My recommendation would be to separate this from the standard Laravel auth, by creating a scond "2FA" middleware. This middleware would check to see if "2fa" sesion variable is set; if not, redirect to the 2FA form. When that form is submitted and the 2FA token verified, the middlware would set the session variable. By applying both the Auth and 2FA middlewares to your routes, you're using 2 levels of security that aren't intrinsically linked in any way.

Comment: Oh, so the 2FA middleware checks if a 2FA session var has been recently been set, if not then it redirects them to the form, if it has been then it passes automatically? I think I misunderstood the other articles explaining the middleware method then. Thanks.

Comment: Yes thats the idea, but you'd have to write your middleware to do that. Middleware itself is just a way of running some code before the controller actions are called; my suggested approach is just one way it could be done, but the articles you mention may describe an alternative technique.

Comment: Thanks. You've given me something to research and think about.

Comment: You could also try this package https://github.com/antonioribeiro/google2fa-laravel - seems to do what you're looking for and is compatible with 5.5.

Comment: I tried that first but was getting some errors that broke composer and artisan so I rolled back my changes and pursued the manual way. Got everything except the auth piece...